# IDataErrorInfo vs IValidatableObject?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, ivalidatableobject

Currently my business objects implement `IDataErrorInfo`. Since I intend to use these libraries in ASP.NET MVC 3, I figure I should implement `IValidatableObject` as well or maybe instead of.

Does WPF work with `IValidatableObject`?

How do DataAnnotations fit into the picture?

Answer (score 2):

`IValidatableObject` is an interface for verifying whole object level errors. It is your responsibility to implemts it by verifying data annotations or other techniques. MVC has native support for data annotations so you can just use them without any further support.

On the contrary wpf ONLY SUPPORTS `IDataErrorInfo`. It has no support for `IValidateObject` or DataAnnotations.

However I implemented a wrapper object that add DataAnnotation support in Wpf to the wrapped object. It furnishes also an implementation of `IPropertyChanged`. See the [Validation Toolkit for Wpf and Silverlight](http://validationtoolkit.codeplex.com/) on codeplex

Answer (score 1):

I am implementing `IValidatableObject` at entity, wrapping it with `IDataErrorInfo` at view model (automatically via base class) for WPF. My entities will work well in either WPF, MVC and new EF CTP5 who also honors `IValidatableObject`.