# IValidatableObject in WPF

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

Can someone upload an example or provide me with some help on implementing IValidatableObject and showing the validation erros on a WPF (MVVM) application using IDataErrorInfo.
I red 3d answer on this post:
[IDataErrorInfo vs IValidatableObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233920/idataerrorinfo-vs-ivalidatableobject/4559267#4559267)

I'm working with net 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the implementation [here](http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2009/10/16/validator.aspx). To quote from the blog post:

> When validating an object, the following process is applied in
>   Validator.ValidateObject:
>
> Validate property-level attributes If any validators are invalid,
>   abort validation returning the failure(s) Validate the object-level
>   attributes If any validators are invalid, abort validation returning
>   the failure(s) If on the desktop framework and the object implements
>   IValidatableObject, then call its Validate method and return any
>   failure(s)

If you have more complex validation needs, it is really recommended to look into [FuentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) library.

Comment: Make it FluentValidation ;) Or you can have a look at EntLib's Validation Application Framework